# Cypress.io/Cucumber - Same function for Given/When/Thens

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

I wanted to know if there was a way Given/When/Then could share code, if it does the exact same thing. Say for instance (not actually using this, just as an example):

```
Given I have searched for {string}
When I search for {string}
Then I will search for {string}
```

And the code for each step is *the exact same*. Is there a way to allow the code to share besides (sometimes) BeforeEach/AfterEach hooks?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve a generic step definition by using `defineStep` as follows:

```js
import { defineStep } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps';

defineStep("I search for {string}", (searchString) => {
  // do something 
})
```

In the feature file you can then use the above step definition as *Given*, *When* or *Then* step, as you would normally do when you define it explicitly as one of them:

```
Feature: Login
    Scenario Outline: Sample
        Given I search for "xyz"
        When I search for "xyz"
        Then I search for "xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I'm not a Cypress user, but all the frameworks I've used with Cucumber ignore (or *can* ignore) the preposition (`Given`/`When`/`Then`). If that's the case or you know how to make that happen with your implementation, the following regex followed by the shared code would do the trick:

`^I (have |will )?search(ed)? for$`

Comment: Unfortunately, Cypress/Cucumber seems to demand the preposition. Here's what the code for a step looks like:
`When("I search for {string}", (string) => {`

Comment: Have you tested this? That's generally the case for writing the function, but at runtime the preposition is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

We use the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor to parse our featurefiles.

The code in our cucumberrunner.js to your cases

> Given I have searched for "string"

could look something like

```
Given|Then|When(/.*?search*?for "(.+?)"/, string => {
    // do something with "string"
});
```

It does ignore the keywords.

(cypress version 6.+)