# Can I have a different step definition for the same method in Cypress with Cucumber Preprocessor?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Can I have a different step definition for the same method in Cypress using Cucumber Preprocessor?

I want to execute the same actions but the step definitions themselves should be different. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Adding an example of what's the actual issue would make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Cypress with [cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor) and your goal is to execute the same action for a different step definition, because this may make more sense from a business point of view, then one possible solution would be the following:

```js
import { defineStep } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps';

defineStep('this is the first step with some param {string}', (param: string) => {
  doSomething(param);
});

defineStep('this is another step also with some param {string}', (param: string) => {
  doSomething(param);
});

function doSomething(param: string) {
  // do anything you like for both step definitions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the answer to [Cypress.io/Cucumber - Same function for Given/When/Thens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70594483/17841663)

We use the regex feature in the functions to match different step definitions.

```
defineStep(/this is.*with some param "string"/, (param: string) => {
  doSomething(param);
});
```